# Positional Awareness

Tags: code-golf, string, source-layout

## Positional Awareness

Your task is to generate a program that, for every permutation of its characters (which includes the original program), outputs the positions of every character relative to the original program.

If your program is

```
Derp
```

you must output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

(or some equivalent). This is because `D` is in the `0`th position, `e` is in the `1`st, r the `2`nd, and `p` the `3`rd.

Let's take another program which is the original program, but with its characters permuted:

```
epDr
```

You must output

```
[1, 3, 0, 2]
```

because `e` is in the `1`st position of the original program, `p` is in the `3`rd position, `D` the `0`th, and `r` the `2`nd.

If the original program has two repeating characters:

```
abcda -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then for the permutation, the `0` and the `4` in the array must be in ascending order:

```
baadc -> [1, 0, 4, 3, 2] (0 first, then 4)
```

## Rules:

- Your program must contain at least two unique characters.
- At most `floor(n/2)` characters are to be the same.

  ```
   aabb (acceptable)
   aaaabc (not acceptable, only floor(6/2) = 3 a's allowed)
  ```
- Your program's output can be either an array (or something similar) containing all the characters' positions in order, or a string with any delimiter, so these are perfectly fine:

  ```
  [0, 1, 2, 3]
  0,1,2,3
  0 1 2 3
  ```

Comment: I don't believe this challenge allows for any non-trivial solution as virtually any answer in any language of length >= ~5 will not be a valid program for every permutation, let alone a program that solves the challenge at hand.

Comment: @orlp What if I reduce it to one permutation? This didn't come up in the sandbox at all, so I didn't realise the problem. I expected this challenge would be like the "Hyperprogramming" one (which was possible), but I guess I'm wrong.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Almost nobody says anything on the sandbox. A while ago, I've posted a question after being in the sandbox for around a month (or so). And only when I've posted it, was when people pointed out mistakes and the downvotes rained. In my honest opinion, the sandbox is useless.

Comment: For once, I feel like in this challenge, a longer answer would be more impressive than a shorter one.

Comment: @Wojowu I can make it [tag:code-bowling], if that's possible - the longest program wins.

Comment: Would the program `12` in R be valid? It would simply print `12` and if permuted; `21`.

Comment: @JamesHolderness I think this might warrant a new question, perhaps with a different criterion than this one. I'll come up with something.

Answer (score 20):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@29o8P8/AA)

This prints

```
0
1
```

while the (only) other permutation

```
01
```

prints

```
1
0
```

#### How it works

In Actually, consecutive digits are parsed separately, so `10` pushes **1** on the stack, then **0** on top of it.

When the program finishes, the stack is printed top to bottom, so it prints **0** first, then a linefeed, then **1**.

The derranged program `01` does the same, in the opposite order.

Comment: Other languages this works in; Seriously, 05ab1e, ///, 2sable.

Comment: The spec says the numbers have to be separated. It does work in Seriously, but Actually is actually just Seriously 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
;J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/t9f8/AA)

Outputs: `[0, 1]`

Other permutation `J;` outputs: `[1, 0]`

#### How it works:

```
;J
;          Concats 0 with...
 J         [1...len(z)], here just [1]

J;
J          [1...len(z)], here just [1]
 ;         ...Concatted with 0
```